# Displaying hidden object on custom UITableViewCell shows on alternate cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a custom cell with imageView and a hidden view created in IB. On double tap on image I un-hide the view. The problem I am seeing is that the view gets displayed in alternate cells of tableview. How do I display the view only on the cell where user tapped.

```
-(void) addRecognizer {
UITapGestureRecognizer *postGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
postGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.postImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.postImageView addGestureRecognizer:postGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void) imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
         [self.headingView setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Example code [STXDynamicTableView](https://github.com/2359media/STXDynamicTableView)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cells get reused as the table view is scrolled. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method needs to reset the view's `hidden` property appropriately.

Comment: I did following to overcome the issue

1. Store indexPath found from tapped cell
2. in cellForRowAtIndexPath check if displayed cell index path matches stored indexPath

if matches, call display view function else call hide view function.

Hope this helps